# Unexpected Behavior with isEven Property on Dart num Type After Type Casting (Downcasting)

Tags: dart

I've encountered an intriguing behavior in Dart related to the `isEven` property when used with the `num` type. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
void main() {
  num a = 3;
  print(a.runtimeType);  // Outputs: int
  // print(a.isEven);  // This line causes a compile-time error
  final b = a as int;
  print(b.runtimeType);  // Outputs: int
  print(a.isEven);       // This line works fine
}
```

When I run the above code, the first invocation of `print(a.isEven)` results in a compile-time error stating that `the getter 'isEven' isn't defined for the class 'num'`
. However, after casting a to `int` (and assigning to `b`), the second `print(a.isEven)` works without any issues.

I understand that `isEven` is a property of `int` and not `double`, but I'm puzzled by the behavior observed here.

1. Why does the second `print(a.isEven)` work even though the type of `a` wasn't changed?
2. Is this a kind of optimization Dart is doing at runtime based on previous type checks or casts?

Would appreciate insights from the Dart community on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the second `print(a.isEven)` work even though the type of a wasn't changed?

It works because by this time, `a` is guaranteed to be an `int` and if it wasn't `int` then your previous code `a as int` would throw an exception.

> Is this a kind of optimization Dart is doing at runtime based on previous type checks or casts?

This is called type promotion (IIRC) and Dart is doing it at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You can *promote* the type of a local variable in a number of ways, but before patterns that was mainly:

- `if (variable != null) ...`  promotes to non-null
- `if (variable is SubType) ...` promotes to a subtype of the current type.

That promotes the variable in the branch that is dominated by the test being true. (Here one piece of code being "dominated" by another means that all control flows going into the former must go through the latter first.)
That's usually just the "true" branch, but it can be extended to code after the test, by making the other branch not complete.

```dart
if (variable == null) return;
// variable promoted to non-null here.
```

or

```dart
if (variable is! SubType) throw BadError("Bad!");
// variable promoted to subtype here.
```

The `v as T` cast is equvialent to `(v is T) ? v /*promoted to T*/ : throw TypeError("...")`, so if you cast to a subtype, it promotes the variable to that subtype in all code dominated by the cast.

Answer (score 0):

See In Dart, `num` represents a numeric type, and type inference infers the type based on context. Properties specific to subclasses like `isEven` for `int`, aren't available when the static type is num. Type conversion with `as` allows treating `num` as `int`, providing that type's properties.

Runtime type checks in Dart are separate from compile-time type inference. And When you done Casting to int informs the compiler, enabling `isEven`. So when first print was there compiler just known `a` as a `num` type, and after you confirm that a is `int` Which enabled the `isEven` property.